# Right Click File Explorer Windows 10 ages to open

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I solved the issue clearing the quick acces history in windows:
See the link below how to do:

[https://www.groovypost.com/howto/clear-windows-10-quick-access-history-file-explorer/#:~:text=Click%20Start%20and%20type%3A%20file,and%20click%20the%20Clear%20button](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/clear-windows-10-quick-access-history-file-explorer/#:%7E:text=Click%20Start%20and%20type%3A%20file,and%20click%20the%20Clear%20button).

I hope it serves you

Comment: [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.